# How to attach current logged in user to object when object is created from django admin

Tags: python, django, request

I'm working on website whose an app which has class called `Members` whose a field that is related to the builtin User class from `django.contrib.auth.models` and it looks like

```
class Members(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    member_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='unknown')
    member_position = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    ...
```

So as you can see when I'm adding `member_image` as a user I have also to select the ***user*** which doesn't make sense to me because I want to detect which user is logged in and pass his/her id as default parameter
like

```
class Members(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=request.user.id)
```

and after remove the user field in the admin panel like

```
class MembersAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ('member_image', 'member_position', ...)
```

so that if the user field doesn't selected it will set the logged in user_id by default

but to access `request` out of the `views.py` is not possible.

so how will I achieve this I also tried the following answers

- [Access session / request information outside of views in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9220484/access-session-request-information-outside-of-views-in-django)
- [Accessing request.user outside views.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12093151/accessing-request-user-outside-views-py)
- [Django: How can I get the logged user outside of view request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16107695/django-how-can-i-get-the-logged-user-outside-of-view-request/16107990#16107990), etc

but still not get it

Comment: I would suggest you to modify MembersAdmin `save_model` method and set current logged in user as user. Checkout this url - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_model

Comment: can you give me a short snippet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify MembersAdmin `save_model` method and attach request.user to the object prior to saving.

```
class MembersAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ('member_image', 'member_position', ...)
    
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        obj.user = request.user
        super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)
```

Answer (score 1):

For exclude the current logged in User for particular page or view, You can try this :-

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
User = user_model()

def some_view(request):
    exclude_current_user = User.objects.exclude(user=request.user)
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution